# Change Language in Export-CSV file from SQL Server through PowerShell ISE

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I need to export a lot of tables from a SQL Server via PowerShell ISE with Danish entries (meaning we have Æ,Ø and Å letters) and the Danish letters are not substituted with question marks ???.

As an example I have this table called `NavnLeg` with this data:

```
Navn    Måned  År
--------------------
Jørgen  3      2019
Arne    4      2018
Åse     7      2018
Hans    2      2017
```

I want to export the table via Powershell (as I have around 70 tables that needs to be copied to a local drive).

When I run the script down below, my CSV file ends up like:

```
Navn    M?ned  ?r
--------------------
J?rgen  3      2019
Arne    4      2018
?se     7      2018
Hans    2      2017
```

This is my current script, where I want to declare, that the CSV-file should use danish letters somehow.

```
Get-ChildItem –Path "E:\Backup" -Recurse | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-60))} | Remove-Item 

$server = "DEV02" 
$database = "Test" 
$tablequery = "SELECT name from sys.tables WHERE NAME IN ('NavnLeg')" 
$date = (date -f yyyy/MM/dd) 

#Declare Connection Variables
$connectionTemplate = "Data Source={0};Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog={1};"
$connectionString = [string]::Format($connectionTemplate, $server, $database)
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString

$command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$command.CommandText = $tablequery
$command.Connection = $connection

$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $command
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$connection.Close()

foreach ($Row in $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    $queryData = "SELECT * FROM [$($Row[0])]"

    $extractFile = "E:\Backup\$($date)_$($Row[0]).csv"

    $command.CommandText = $queryData
    $command.Connection = $connection

    $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $command
    $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
    $connection.Close()

    $DataSet.Tables[0]  | Export-Csv $extractFile -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Comment: Try adding `-Encoding UTF8` to the `Export-Csv` cmdlet

Comment: Sublime! That works perfectly :) Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Export-CSV defaults to ASCII on PowerShell 5.1. The `-Encoding` parameter specifies the type of encoding for the target file, you can choose from `ASCII, BigEndianUnicode, Default, OEM, Unicode, UTF7, UTF8, UTF32`

As per my comment, UTF8 is a good choice.